# A few questions(typescript, c#, filesystem)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, typescript

I have two different files and they are in the same folder and I want to work with them.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I make this work(combining c# and html in a .cshtml ) ?
   `<script src="~/Views/path/path/01/"+@Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.VirtualPath)+‌​‌​".js"></script>`
2. Why doesn't it not work (the file is in the same folder) ?

   `<script src="test.js"></script>`

   , nor this :

   `<script src="/test.js"></script>`

   the only thing that works:

   `<script src="~/Views/path/path/01/test.js"></script>`
3. Is there a reason to have `.ts` and `.cshtml` not in the same folder ?

   Thank You for helping

Comment: For the first question: Try src='@"~//Views//path//path//01//" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.VirtualPath)+‌​‌​".js"'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite generic questions, but I will try to help:

1. You can use `@Href()` or `@Url.Content()` and pass your virtual path as an argument. It will be resolved correctly.
2. Because you need an absolute URL or a relative one - but relative to the working directory of your app, not file.
3. How you structure your application is up to you. One prefers storing all separately, one has a completely different approach.

Comment: @99999 Because you got only file name. Try `@Url.Content(this.VirtualPath)`.

Comment: @99999 You should use `@Url.Content(this.VirtualPath.Replace(".cshtml",".ts"))` then.